# JSON.stringify produces empty object {}

Tags: javascript, json, object, webrtc

I try to get the value of an event object from Google Chrome (WebRTC framework). My method looks like this:

```
yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    console.log("onicecandidate called on my side with event: "
        + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4)); //that last line produces {}

    var result = "";
    for (var key in event) {
        result += (key + " : " + event[key]);
    }
    console.log(result);
    //...
}
```

While JSON.stringify does not work, the loop produces result like ...

```
  candidate : [object RTCIceCandidate], NONE : 0, CAPTURING_PHASE : 1, AT_TARGET : 2, BUBBLING_PHASE : 3, MOUSEDOWN : 1, MOUSEUP : 2, MOUSEOVER : 4, MOUSEOUT : 8, MOUSEMOVE : 16, MOUSEDRAG : 32, CLICK : 64, DBLCLICK : 128, KEYDOWN : 256, KEYUP : 512, KEYPRESS : 1024, DRAGDROP : 2048, FOCUS : 4096, BLUR : 8192, SELECT : 16384, CHANGE : 32768, type : icecandidate, target : [object RTCPeerConnection], currentTarget : [object RTCPeerConnection], eventPhase : 2, bubbles : false, cancelable : false, defaultPrevented : false, timeStamp : 246.52, path : , srcElement : [object RTCPeerConnection], returnValue : true, cancelBubble : false, stopPropagation : function stopPropagation() { [native code] }, stopImmediatePropagation : function stopImmediatePropagation() { [native code] }, preventDefault : function preventDefault() { [native code] }, initEvent : function initEvent() { [native code] }, composed : false, composedPath : function composedPath() { [native code] },
```

I don't really want to make things complicated and use recursion in order to get the subproperties of the properties. So is there no way to output the properties of the object in a nice and clean way? Why does JSON.stringify give me an empty object?

Also, why can I only loop through an object using the for each loop, while

```
 for (var i = 0; i<event.length; i++) result += (event[i] + event[event[i]] );
```

does not iterate? I am new to Javascript, sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: This is for purposes of inspection? If so, maybe you want to use `console.dir` (without the string concatenation) instead of `console.log`?

Comment: Stringify will only reach owned, enumerable properties, so any property of any object that doesn't meet that criteria will not be processed. And you wrote that a `for each` loop works. I assume you actually meant the `for-in` loop works, while the `for` doesn't. That's because `event` has no `.length`, and its properties are not numeric indices. A `for-in` loop is a general property enumerator, that visits all enumerable properties, including inherited ones.

Comment: then how do I use something along the lines of hasNext(), because I cannot use if(i < event.length-1) in a for-in loop?

Comment: You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all own *(non-inherited)* property names whether or not they're enumerable, and then use a `for` loop over that. You'll still need to handle nested objects recursively, but that's really not complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event most likely has  no WebIDL JSON serializer.
If you're only interested in onicecandidate, you should call JSON.stringify on the event.candidate (which may not exist to signal the end of candidates) -- see also the example in the [webrtc specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example)